# Swap and group column names in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with some quantitative data and one qualitative data. I would like to use describe to compute stats and group by column using the qualitative data. But I do not obtain the order I want for the level. Hereafter is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.random.random(10) for k in "ABC"})
df["qual"] = 5 * ["init"] + 5 * ["final"]
```

The `DataFrame` looks like:

```
          A         B         C   qual
0  0.298217  0.675818  0.076533   init
1  0.015442  0.264924  0.624483   init
2  0.096961  0.702419  0.027134   init
3  0.481312  0.910477  0.796395   init
4  0.166774  0.319054  0.645250   init
5  0.609148  0.697818  0.151092  final
6  0.715744  0.067429  0.761562  final
7  0.748201  0.803647  0.482738  final
8  0.098323  0.614257  0.232904  final
9  0.033003  0.590819  0.943126  final
```

Now I would like to group by the `qual` column and compute statistical descriptors using `describe`. I did the following:

```
ddf = df.groupby("qual").describe().transpose()
ddf.unstack(level=0)
```

And I got

```
qual      final                          init                    
              A         B         C         A         B         C
count  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
mean   0.440884  0.554794  0.514284  0.211741  0.574539  0.433959
std    0.347138  0.284931  0.338057  0.182946  0.274135  0.355515
min    0.033003  0.067429  0.151092  0.015442  0.264924  0.027134
25%    0.098323  0.590819  0.232904  0.096961  0.319054  0.076533
50%    0.609148  0.614257  0.482738  0.166774  0.675818  0.624483
75%    0.715744  0.697818  0.761562  0.298217  0.702419  0.645250
max    0.748201  0.803647  0.943126  0.481312  0.910477  0.796395
```

I am close to what I want but I would like to swap and group the column index such as:

```
                       A               B               C
qual      initial  final  initial  final  initial  final
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`columns.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and then [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by `level=0` and `axis='columns'`:

```
ddf = df.groupby('qual').describe().T.unstack(level=0)

ddf.columns = ddf.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
ddf = ddf.sort_index(level=0, axis='columns')
```

Or in one line using [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) instead of `index.swaplevel`:

```
ddf = ddf.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis='columns')
```

```
          A          B          C     
qual  final init final init final init
count  5.00 5.00  5.00 5.00  5.00 5.00
mean   0.44 0.21  0.55 0.57  0.51 0.43
std    0.35 0.18  0.28 0.27  0.34 0.36
min    0.03 0.02  0.07 0.26  0.15 0.03
25%    0.10 0.10  0.59 0.32  0.23 0.08
50%    0.61 0.17  0.61 0.68  0.48 0.62
75%    0.72 0.30  0.70 0.70  0.76 0.65
max    0.75 0.48  0.80 0.91  0.94 0.80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **ddf.stack().unstack(level=[0,2])**, inplace of ddf.unstack(level=0)